# UPDATE with OUTER APPLY and WHERE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to anonymize the users in my database. So I got this working with an `OUTER APPLY`. I also need to need to add a `WHERE` clause though.

```
UPDATE u 
SET [Name] = rnd.name
FROM [dbo].[User] AS u
OUTER APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 name 
            FROM (VALUES ('Roger'), ('Kyle')) n(name)
            WHERE u.id = u.Id ORDER BY newid()) AS rnd;
```

Now I want to add a `WHERE [Name] != 'Pete'`. How can I do that?

Comment: UPDATE u 
SET [Name] = rnd.name
FROM [dbo].[User] AS u
OUTER APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 name 
            FROM (VALUES ('Roger'), ('Kyle')) n(name)
            WHERE u.id = u.Id ORDER BY newid() ) AS rnd
  where  u.name != 'Pete'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you don't need `outer apply`.  Then you can filter in the `where` clause:

```
UPDATE u 
    SET [Name] = rnd.name
    FROM [dbo].[User] u CROSS APPLY
         (SELECT TOP 1 name 
          FROM (VALUES ('Roger'), ('Kyle')) n(name)
          WHERE u.id IS NOT NULL   -- correlation clause needed to prevent optimization
          ORDER BY newid()
         ) rnd
    WHERE u.name <> 'Pete';
```